# Parallelogram law for vectors of equal length

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

Does the parallelogram law for vectors of equal length imply the full parallelogram law? That is,
if for all norm one vectors $x$ and $y$ in a Banach space $X$ it holds that $\lVert x-y\rVert^2+\lVert x+y\rVert^2=4$, does it follow that $X$ is isometric to a Hilbert space?

I suspect the answer is "no", but I cannot come up with an example. Of course, it is enough to consider the question in two dimensions.

Comment: You might consider to change the title to *Parallelogram law for vectors of equal length*.

Comment: The answer is yes, see Theorem 2 in <https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1952-003-06/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9.pdf>.

Comment: According to the linked article the positive solution is due to M.M. Day.

Comment: @user42355 You should post your comment as an answer. If possible, it would be nice to briefly sketch the proof.

Comment: Title of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428410/parallelogram-law-for-vectors-of-equal-length#comment1102032_428410) by @user42355: [Schoenberg - A remark on M. M. Day’s characterization of inner-product spaces and a conjecture of L. M. Blumenthal](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give it a try, based on Day's idea. Let $X$ be a two-dimensional Banach space with the given property and denote by $B_X$ its unit ball. Consider the ellipsoid of maximal volume (denoted by $B_2$) contained in $B_X$ (the John's ellipsoid) and denote by $\|\cdot\|_2$ the induced Euclidean norm. The goal is to show that $B_X=B_2$.

From John's theorem concerning the ellipsoid of maximal volume (or Loewner's Lemma for two dimensions in Day's paper), it follows that $B_X$ and $B_2$ have at least four contact points. Unless $B_X=B_2$, the contact points cannot form a dense subset of $B_X$. Assuming $B_X\neq B_2$, we can find contact points $x$ and $y$ such that $\displaystyle\frac{x+y}{\|x+y\|}\in B_X$ is not a contact point. Hence $\|x+y\|<\|x+y\|_2$. Therefore:

$$
4=\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2<\|x+y\|_2^2+\|x-y\|_2^2=4
$$

This is a contradiction, hence $B_X=B_2$.

Comment: @user42355 mentioned (in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428410/parallelogram-law-for-vectors-of-equal-length#comment1102032_428410)) a paper [Schoenberg - A remark on M. M. Day’s characterization of inner-product spaces and a conjecture of L. M. Blumenthal](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1952-0052035-9) explaining, as you indicate, that this is due to Day.